# Can I use a different wireless receiver dongle for the Logitech MX Master mouse?

Tags: logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

Wireless receiver dongles for the Logitech MX Revolution mouse are hard to find.

In case it gets broken or lost, can I use another type of receiver with this mouse?

Answer (score 3):

The MX Revolution has two editions: `06` and `07`.

Both come with their own receiver and these are not cross compatible -- even though they look nearly identical.  See [Logitech's help page](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/article/9338?product=a0qi00000069usMAAQ) about this.

The MX Revolution is not a 'Unifying' device so it can not be paired with the tiny Logitech Unifying wireless adapter.

However, I've had some luck with an `07` mouse which could be paired with a wireless adapter from an MX 1100 mouse.

So in summary:

- The `07` edition (part number `810-000422`) is compatible with *MX Revolution* receivers `810-000412` or `810-000826`
- But `07` can also be paired with with *MX 1100* receiver `810-000824`.
- The `06` edition (part number `831869-0000`) is compatible with its native receiver `831735-1000`.

There may be other combinations that work too.

The receivers don't support multiple devices, so they can only be paired with one device at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the great self-answered question. Why Logitech still wants to use proprietary dongles in 2023 is a mind boggling thing. It’s it easier to just make them all Bluetooth devices? Anyway, nice work compiling this info.