# Connecting Logitech MX Revolution Mouse to a MX1100 receiver

Tags: logitech-mouse

I have a 07 MX Revolution mouse with no receiver.
I also have a MX1100 incl. receiver.
According to [Can I use a different wireless receiver dongle for the Logitech MX Master mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/1356096/can-i-use-a-different-wireless-receiver-dongle-for-the-logitech-mx-master-mouse) there is a way to connect the Revolution 07 to the MX1100 dongle. The only problem is that the dongle is still connected to the MX1000 when I open the SetPoint app and there is no option to unlinked them, which would allow to connect the Revolution to the receiver.
Is there anyway to disconnect the receiver from the MX1100 so it can be avaiable for a new connection?

Thx in advance for any help.

Comment: Problem solved. Using Connection Utility Software https://support.logi.com/hc/pl/articles/360025141574-Logitech-Connection-Utility-Software

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should turn your comment into an answer.